# How to sub-string elements of a vector in R

Tags: r, substring

I have a vector of strings, all containing a common symbol lets say "*". I need to delete the * and all characters after that for all vector elements. For example:
In abcd*123 I need to have abcd. The number of characters, before and after * are various.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: `sub("\\*.*", "", 'abc*123')`

Comment: `sapply(strsplit('abc*123', "\\*"), "[", 1)` may do well for speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
out <- gsub("\\*.*", "", yourVector)
```